# Проблема с кодировкой yandex translate api

Tags: php, кодировка, utf-8

Проблема с кодировкой.

```
file_get_contents("https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=_KEY_&text=Привет&lang=en")
```

Пробую на windows (openserver), получаю:

> object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["code"]=> int(200) ["lang"]=> string(5)
>   "ru-en" ["text"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "Hi" } }

Пробую на linux:

> object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["code"]=> int(200) ["lang"]=> string(5)
>   "en-en" ["text"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(21) "Ð_Ñ_Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ_" } }

Файл в utf-8, .htaccess AddDefaultCharset UTF-8.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Если передавать `lang=ru_en` ? Хотя, автодект языка, скорее всего, не сработал из-за кривой кодировки.

Answer (score 1):

Открываем документацию https://tech.yandex.ru/translate/doc/dg/reference/translate-docpage/ и видим что

**lang**: Направление перевода.
Может задаваться одним из следующих способов:

1. В виде пары кодов языков («с какого»-«на какой»), разделенных дефисом. Например, en-ru обозначает перевод с английского на русский.
2. В виде кода конечного языка (например ru). В этом случае сервис пытается определить исходный язык автоматически.

В вашем случае Linux Вам ясно говорит что перевод идет с языка EN на язык EN через

```
["lang"]=> string(5) "en-en"
```

Поэтому воспользуйтесь документацией и пропишите направление перевода явно (как указал [@br3t](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/221753/br3t) в комментарии). Если проблема с кракозябрами останется - значит кодировка.

```
file_get_contents("https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=_KEY_&text=Привет&lang=ru_en")
```